# Supplying NumPy site.cfg arguments to pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip, intel-mkl

I'm using NumPy built against Intel's Math Kernel Library.  I use virtualenv, and typically use pip to install packages.

However, in order for NumPy to find the MKL libraries, it's necessary to create a site.cfg file in the NumPy source directory prior to compiling it, then manually build and install.  I could script this whole process, but I was hoping for a simpler solution.

I have a standard site.cfg file that can be used for this purpose under version control.  Are there any pip command line options that will tell it to copy a particular file to the source directory before building a package?

Alternatively, are there any environment variables that can be set instead of supplying the library paths in a site.cfg file?  Here is the site.cfg file that I use.  It was taken almost verbatim from [Intel's site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl).

```
[mkl]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64
include_dirs = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/include
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs =
```

For reference, I'm running Ubuntu, Python 2.7, and NumPy 1.6.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the source (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/site.cfg.example):

> To assist automatic installation like easy_install, the user's home directory
>   will also be checked for the file ~/.numpy-site.cfg .

Is that a workable solution? You'd still need to preload the home directories with the global .numpy-site.cfg, but you wouldn't have to muck with the build or installation after that.

Comment: Yeah, that could definitely work.  Thanks.  I'll leave this open for a little while longer though, to see if anyone comes up with a simpler solution.

Comment: @joshayers How did you write your `~/.numpy-site.cfg`? I have no luck in providing MKL's BLAS to Scipy. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22067761/688080

Comment: As an extra, I wanted to install `scikits.audiolab` so I put into `~/.numpy-site.cfg` the lines under `site.cfg` from https://github.com/cournape/audiolab/issues/7

Answer (score 7):

I ended up putting together a script to automate this.  Here it is, in case it can help someone else.  I've tested it in Python 2.7, but it should work elsewhere without significant modifications.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import io
import os.path
import re
import subprocess
import urllib2

# This downloads, builds, and installs NumPy against the MKL in the
# currently active virtualenv

file_name = 'numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz'
url = ('http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/'
       'numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz/download')

def main():

    # download NumPy and unpack it
    file_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    with io.open(file_name, 'wb') as fobj:
        fobj.write(file_data)
    subprocess.check_call('tar -xvf {0}'.format(file_name), shell=True)
    base_name = re.search(r'(.*)\.tar\.gz$', file_name).group(1)
    os.chdir(base_name)

    # write out a site.cfg file in the build directory
    site_cfg = (
        '[mkl]\n'
        'library_dirs = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64\n'
        'include_dirs = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/include\n'
        'mkl_libs = mkl_rt\n'
        'lapack_libs =\n')
    with io.open('site.cfg', 'wt', encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
        fobj.write(site_cfg)

    # build and install NumPy
    subprocess.check_call('python setup.py build', shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call('python setup.py install', shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your goal of installing NumPy to use Intel's Math Kernel Library is now *much* easier since [Intel created pips](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-distribution-for-python-and-intel-performance-libraries-with-pip-and) to install MKL + NumPy:

```
pip uninstall numpy -y  # if the standard numpy is present
pip install intel-numpy
```

as well as `intel-scipy`, `intel-scikit-learn`, `pydaal`, `tbb4py`, `mkl_fft`, `mkl_random`, and the lower level packages if you need just them. Again, you must first uninstall the standard packages if they're already installed in your virtualenv.

**NOTE:**

> If standard NumPy, SciPy and Scikit-Learn packages are already installed, the packages must be uninstalled  before installing the Intel® variants of these packages(intel-numpy etc) to avoid any conflicts. As mentioned earlier, pydaal uses intel-numpy, hence it is important to first remove the standard Numpy library (if installed) and then install pydaal.

Comment: Until I read this post I had no idea that Intel itself had finally done something to make this easy. That's nifty!

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, are there any environment variables that can be set instead of supplying the library paths in a site.cfg file?

[NumPy 1.21 introduces environment variables](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html?highlight=npy_blas_order#accelerated-blas-lapack-libraries) for this purpose.

E.g.

```sh
NPY_BLAS_ORDER=MKL NPY_LAPACK_ORDER=MKL pip install numpy --no-binary numpy
```

to auto-detect the MKL library when installing NumPy from source code. If needed, you can set the environment variables `NPY_BLAS_LIBS`, `NPY_CBLAS_LIBS`, and `NPY_LAPACK_LIBS` to linker CLI options which put your chosen libraries on the linker path.

This is easier for a script to do than creating a `~/.numpy-site.cfg` file,

```
[openblas]
libraries = openblas
library_dirs = /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib
include_dirs = /usr/local/opt/openblas/include
runtime_library_dirs = /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib
```

then running

```
pip install numpy --no-binary numpy
```

BTW, the file `~/.numpy-site.cfg` also works when installing scipy from source code:

```
pip install scipy --no-binary scipy
```

**NOTE:** If you're still using Python 2.7, install numpy then install scipy. [Attempting](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10749) to install them together will:

- invoke a SciPy easy_install installer that requests NumPy,
- load the latest NumPy installer (even if you specifically asked pip to `install numpy==1.14.6 scipy==1.0.1 --no-binary numpy,scipy`), then
- fail with `RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required` because the latest NumPy does not support Python 2.7.