# Why did matrix multiplication using python's numpy become so slow after upgrading ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04, matrix-multiplication, ubuntu-14.04

I used to have Ubuntu 12.04 and recently did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.  The stuff I'm working on involves multiplications of big matrices (~2000 X 2000), for which I'm using numpy.  The problem I'm having is that now the calculations are taking 10-15 times longer.

Going from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 implied going from Python 2.7.3 to 2.7.6 and from numpy 1.6.1 to 1.8.1.  However, I think that the issue might have to do with the linear algebra libraries that numpy is linked to.  Instead of **libblas.so.3gf** and **liblapack.so.3gf**, I can only find **libblas.so.3** and **liblapack.so.3**.

I also installed libopenblas and libatlas:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libatlas3-base
```

and tried them, but the slowdown doesn't change.  So, my questions are:

1. What's the difference between the packages with and without the "gf"?
2. Is this possibly causing the slowdown in the matrix multiplications?
3. If so, how can I go back to libblas.so.3gf and liblapack.so.3gf?  They seem to be discontinued in Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 5):

wim is correct, in that the problem is probably caused by numpy linking to a slower BLAS library (e.g. the reference CBLAS library rather than ATLAS).

You can check which BLAS library is being linked at runtime by calling the `ldd` utility on one of numpy's compiled shared libraries.

For example, if you installed numpy in the standard location using `apt-get`:

```
~$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
        ...
        libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f01f0188000)
        ...
```

This output tells me that numpy is linked against `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`. This is usually a symlink to the reference CBLAS library, which is pretty slow.

You could, as wim suggests, remove the version of numpy installed via `apt-get` and build it yourself, either using `pip` or by downloading the source directly. However, I would **strongly** discourage you from using `sudo pip install ...` to install Python modules system-wide. This is a bad habit to get into, since you run the risk of breaking dependencies in your system-wide Python environment.

It is much safer to either install into your `~/.local/` directory using `pip install --user ...` or even better, to install into a completely self-contained [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Another option would be to use [`update-alternatives`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to force your system-wide numpy to link against a different BLAS library. I've written a [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21673585/1461210) that shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing numpy through package manager?

If so, I recommend to go through pip instead so you can clearly see in the build process what is being successfully linked during setup.

1. Remove the apt version (`sudo apt-get purge python-numpy`)
2. Install build-deps headers and static libraries (`sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran`), maybe there are some others but these are the ones I remember.
3. `pip install numpy`