# performance of NumPy with different BLAS implementations

Tags: numpy, amazon-ec2, blas, accelerate-framework, openblas

I'm running an algorithm that is implemented in Python and uses NumPy. The most computationally expensive part of the algorithm involves **solving a set of linear systems** (i.e. a call to `numpy.linalg.solve()`. I came up with this small benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Create two large random matrices
a = np.random.randn(5000, 5000)
b = np.random.randn(5000, 5000)

t1 = time.time()
# That's the expensive call:
np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print time.time() - t1
```

I've been running this on:

1. My laptop, a late 2013 MacBook Pro 15" with 4 cores at 2GHz (`sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` gives me *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4750HQ CPU @ 2.00GHz*)
2. An Amazon EC2 `c3.xlarge` instance, with 4 vCPUs. Amazon advertises them as "High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processors"

Bottom line:

- On the Mac it runs in **~4.5 seconds**
- On the EC2 instance it runs in **~19.5 seconds**

I have tried it also on other OpenBLAS / Intel MKL based setups, and the runtime is always comparable  to what I get on the EC2 instance (modulo the hardware config.)

**Can anyone explain why the performance on Mac (with the Accelerate Framework) is > 4x better?** More details about the NumPy / BLAS setup in each are provided below.

### Laptop setup

`numpy.show_config()` gives me:

```
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

### EC2 instance setup:

On Ubuntu 14.04, I installed OpenBLAS with

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
```

When installing NumPy, I created a `site.cfg` with the following contents:

```
[default]
library_dirs= /usr/lib/openblas-base

[atlas]
atlas_libs = openblas
```

`numpy.show_config()` gives me:

```
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Haswell has 2x the raw compute of Ivybridge per cycle per core (due to inclusion of FMA).  I wonder if your openblas was built without AVX support enabled?  That would give another 2x.

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25346036/1461210). Can you check whether your EC2 instance is actually multithreading BLAS operations?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behavior could be that Accelerate uses multithreading, while the others don't.

Most BLAS implementations follow the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to determine how many threads to use.  I believe they only use 1 thread if not told otherwise explicitly.
[Accelerate's man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/Accelerate.7.html), however sounds like threading is turned on by default; it can be turned off by setting the environment variable `VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS`.

To determine if this is really what's happening, try

```
export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1
```

before calling the Accelerate version, and

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

for the other versions.

Independent of whether this is really the reason, it's a good idea to always set these variables when you use BLAS to be sure you control what is going on.

Comment: Linked to Accelerate, `VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS` does affect `numpy.linalg.norm`'s performance.  `scipy.linalg.norm` on the other hand is consistently slower and not affected by the variable which leads me to believe that it's not linked to Accelerate but instead uses reference LAPACK.

Comment: Thanks Elmar. Fwiw, [scipy.linalg.norm](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/misc.py) does `if ord in (None, 2) and (a.ndim == 1): nrm2 = get_blas_funcs('nrm2')`; `norm` in [numpy.linalg.linalg](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py) says "# Immediately handle some default, simple, fast, and common cases". Altogether, too complex.