# Limit number of threads in numpy

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

It seems that my numpy library is using 4 threads, and setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` does not stop this.

`numpy.show_config()` gives me these results:

```
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
atlas_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
```

So I know it is using blas, but I can't figure out how to make it use 1 thread for matrix multiplication.

Comment: [Atlas defines number of threads at compile time](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tnum)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There are a few common multi CPU libraries that are used for numerical computations, including inside of NumPy. There are a few environment flags that you can set **before running the script** to limit the number of CPUS that they use.

Try setting all of the following:

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

Sometimes it's a bit tricky to see where exactly multithreading is introduced.

Other answers show environment flags for other libraries. They may also work.

Comment: This needs more details.

Comment: On Macs, `export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1`; see [performance-of-numpy-with-different-blas-implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511430/performance-of-numpy-with-different-blas-implementations) on SO. Beware: `man Accelerate` says "the
     value of VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS may be cached by the library and reused; if you need
     to ensure single-threaded execution, you should set VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS before
     making any Accelerate calls"

Comment: What is the best way to do this _from within the script_? Should I just run `os.system("export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1")`? I've read mixed reviews of whether or not that will work correctly, and even if it does, is that the best way to do this? It seems a little hacky for some reason.

Comment: For anyone else who had the same question as me above, per this thread `http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Set-threads-from-within-python-code-td44108.html` you can do `os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"` etc but you have to put that *before* you have `import numpy`. Apparently numpy only checks for this at import.

Comment: @seth127 You should make this an answer IMO, it's useful.

Comment: I agree. The comment by Seth should be an accepted answer

Comment: In 2022, 
```os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1' os.environ['NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS'] = '1' os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'```works even if added after import `numpy`

Answer (score 67):

There are more than the 3 mentioned environmental variables. The followings are the complete list of environmental variables and the package that uses that variable to control the number of threads it spawns. Note than you need to set these variables before doing `import numpy`:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS: openmp,
OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS: openblas,
MKL_NUM_THREADS: mkl,
VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS: accelerate,
NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS: numexpr
```

So in practice you can do:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "4" # export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "4" # export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "6" # export MKL_NUM_THREADS=6
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "4" # export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=4
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "6" # export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=6
```

Note that as of November 2018 the Numpy developers are working on making this possible to do after you do `import numpy` as well. I'll update this post once they commit those changes.

Comment: On some clusters I have found that I need to do the export in the shell and that the os.environ doesn't work.

Comment: @Amir Has there already been an update on the numpy library for these environmental variables?

Comment: Hello, any updates on this?

Comment: I am quite curious about this as well, my use case benefits from letting numpy multithread during initialization, and then restricting it to one thread when doing multi-processing.

Answer (score 35):

In regards to doing this *from within a python script* as opposed to at the bash prompt, per [this thread](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Set-threads-from-within-python-code-td44108.html)  you can do the following (same commands as the answer above):

```
import os
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

but **you have to put that *before* you do `import numpy`.** Apparently numpy only checks for this at import.

(this is reposted as an answer based on @kηives comment above.)

Comment: I believe there's also OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS if you've linked against OpenBLAS.

Comment: Actually, this is being set not when you import numpy, but when you first invoke MKL-optimized Numpy code. For example, np.ones() does not trigger reading these variables, but np.dot() does.

Answer (score 21):

After trying a number of the solutions above without luck, I found a reference to [threadpoolctl](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl) in the Numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html). This worked and it can be used even if numpy is already imported.

```py
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_limits

with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api='blas'):
  # single threaded numpy code...
```

Just make sure to use the `user_api` which is listed when you do:

```
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_info
from pprint import pprint
import numpy
pprint(threadpool_info())
```

Comment: Is there any way to set this once, at the beginning of a notebook or script? I don't want to have to change my codebase to wrap parts of it in this context manager, and I don't want to try to wrap an entire script under this with statement (won't work with e.g. an iPython notebook split over multiple cells).

Comment: @MRule you are best off setting the environment varibles all to '1' before executing your script in that case (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this at run-time the following way:

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(1)
```

I use the following code to make this snippet less likely to cause problems in scripts/packages:

```
try:
    import mkl
    mkl.set_num_threads(1)
except:
    pass
```