# What's the reason for numpy that has different parallel rate under different Python environment?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have mainly used *numpy* and *joblib* to constructe a machine learning pkg. I developed it on Python3.5.x. The *numpy* mainly played a role in the computation part and *joblib* devoted to implement the parallel part. While I had completed the development process under Python3.5.x. I re-tested the pkg on Python3.6.x and Python3.7.x. The pkg under Python3.5.x went well that used the number I set of CPUs while under Python3.6.x used less CPUs and under Python3.7.x used almost half of CPUs of my computer.

Comment: Can you add some more details. E.g. a table  of your results

Comment: I used Parallel in joblib to implement multi-threads and set the number of workers (CPUs) to ten. The pkg run well in the Python3.5.x which used ten CPUs as I  wished. However, when I re-test the pkg under Python3.7.x, all of my CPUs was included in that computation even though the number of workers I set still equaled to ten. I have tried to use environment variable such as MKL_NUM_THREADS 
refering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy. This was worked for Python3.7.x, but for Python3.6.x and Python3.8.x, it didn't work.

Comment: I think this may be  related to the version of numpy.