# Python multiprocessing uses all cores even when limited

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module from Python in order to speed-up my code, but for some reason the program ends up using more than the number of cores I specify. Indeed, when looking at `htop` to check the core usage, I see that all 60 available cores are used at times instead of 10 as needed.

As an example, this code already produces the behavior:

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def square(i):
    size = 10000
    return np.dot(np.random.normal(size=size), np.random.normal(size=(size, size)) @ np.random.normal(size=size))

with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
    t = pool.map(square, range(100))
```

I am running this in a Jupyter Notebook inside a JupyterHub. Up until a few hours ago, everything was running smoothly (meaning that the number of cores used was not going beyond 10), the only big change that happened is that I updated all my packages via `conda update --all` and specifically updated scipy with  `conda install -c conda-forge scipy`. However I have no idea what could have caused the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit number of threads in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy)

Comment: I heard of that one and tried but it still doesn't work for some reason. I'm not entirely sure also, should I include the `os.environ[...]` stuff in every `.py` file that uses NumPy, or should it be enough if added in the Jupyter Notebook I use to run stuff? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alright, `import mkl` and `mkl.set_num_threads(1)` solved it!