# Python Import and Pickle CPU Time Peak

Tags: python, io, benchmarking, python-module

I want to get the CPU time of a python module I developed for benchmarking. I call it via a CLI after installing it with pip install.
While the wall-clock-time is fine, I observed peaks in the CPU time when starting the app (around 7 seconds) and loading pickle files (LightGBM models, around 23 seconds for 7 models). So in sum around 30 seconds, while the wall-clock -time is around 1 second.
Here is how I call the pickle load:

```
def get_model(name):
    model = None
    if name == "median":
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'median_model.pkl'), 'rb') as model_file:
            model = pickle.load(model_file)
    elif name == "lower_5":
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'low_model_5.pkl'), 'rb') as model_file:
            model = pickle.load(model_file)
    elif name == "lower_10":
...
```

The starting CPU time seems to be a result of a import of one of my custom modules:

```
from mymodule.Prediction.predictor import Predictor
```

without this import, the CPU time difference of 7 seconds vanishes.

Everything is sequentially, no multiprocessing what so ever. So I was wondering why those two procedures create such a large CPU time and are using multiple threads/cores.

So why exactly are those two operations using multiple threads? How can I prevent this?

Many thanks in advance!

The only way I could handle it right know is by assigning a fix core with `taskset -c 0`, but I can not do this in production or even on windows.

EDIT: I use the "time" command under linux to get the CPU time. I also tried "perf", same result.
EDIT2: The import CPU time is actually due to: from scipy.stats import entropy. As soon as I remove this line, the 7 seconds additional CPU time are gone ...

Comment: I found the solution. Multiple numpy imports were responsible for the CPU time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy solved it for me.