# What is the best way to scale up Gensim Doc2Vec training?

Tags: nlp, gensim, distributed

I have one million documents.  I chunk those documents up into 20 million paragraphs (each paragraph is about 50 words) to train a Doc2Vec model with.  It currently takes about 20 hours to train the model with these paragraphs and I would like to speed this up (it only takes 15 mins to build the vocabulary).  Gensim never uses more than 4 cores during training (no matter how many cores I have available).  I know there are issues with the Python GIL that may be the cause of this.

Here's the code I use to train the Doc2Vec model:

```
model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=3, epochs=40, workers=24, dm=0, window=3, dbow_words=0, sample=0.00010, negative=15, ns_exponent=0.75)
model.build_vocab(training_corpus)
model.train(training_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=40)
```

Is there a way to distribute this across multiple machines so I can train the model more quickly?

Comment: How (in code) are you initializing the model & launching training? (Editing your question to add thia info will be easier to read than squeezing it into a comment.) What indicated to you that only 4 cores were being used? How many cores will be available? How many words, on average, per document?

Comment: I've updated my question to include a code sample and a few more details.  I view the number of cores being used with top.  I can have up to 128 cores, but my code example is only using 24 cores.  There are about 50 words per paragraph, which is what I submit to Doc2Vec as a document.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim has no support for distributing `Doc2Vec` training over multiple machines.

With your `workers=24`, Gensim's `Doc2Vec` will spawn 24 worker threads – in addition to the main/master that's reading the corpus & parceling out batches of documents to each worker. So potentially up-to-25 cores will be at least a little active – but when you see something in `top` like "400%", that may mean each of 25 cores is only about 16% in-use, due to other bottlenecks.

In particular, the classic & Pythonic manner of supplying the corpus as an iterable, plus Gensim using a single thread to split up that corpus, and Gensim only having moved the innermost raw calculations into fully-immune-to-the-Python-GIL into raw Cython/C code, means it has a hard time keeping more than around 12 threads busy at once (and thus ~1200% utilization reported by `top`).

In fact, past a certain optimium number of workers that's affected by your other corpus details & model parameters, trying to use more threads starts to hurt, from contention/switching overhead.

So: holding the rest of your setup/model-parameters constant, if you want to  achieve the maximum training core utilization in this corpus mode, you'd need to experiment with different `workers` values & watch the logging-reported words-per-second for each over a few representative minutes, and pick the `workers` value that reports best. Notably:

- The optimal value in the corpus mode you're using is likely to be in the range 4-16.
- As long as your corpus isn't wildly different in ts doc lengths and words-used in different ranges, the 1st few minutes of `train()` should be representative of the entire run – so you can start a run, estimate its rate, & interrupt it.
- To not have to pay the `build_vocab()` cost each time – a step which requires a full pass and also remains single-threaded – you can `.save()` the model after `.build_vocab()`, then re-`.load()` repeatedly, tamper with the internal `workers` value, then run `.train()` for each trial.

A few other speed-of-training factors to consider:

- If your `training_corpus` is doing *anything* other than reading an already-tokenized corpus from RAM or a fast volume – like accessing a DB or performing extra preprocessing – it will be an even bigger limit on how busy the workers can get. So it's often best to do those things in a prior step, saving the result as a plain-text space-delimited local-fast-volume corpus – or even, in plentiful-RAM situations, already Python list-of-lists-of-strings.
- The optimal number of workers given contention issues is most affected by a few of the parameters that make each individual training-example intense, especially 'window', 'negative', & 'vector_size'. Each of these, when larger, typically slows training versus a smaller value, ceteris paribus. BUT, by making the blocks of optimized (Python-GIL-immune) calculation run longer, larger values here *increase* the achievable core-utilization. So in experimenting with parameters, if you have more cores than this corpus-mode can usually saturate, it may be 'nearly free' to try higher values in some of these parameters, because all the extra calc-costs soak up cores that'd otherwise be idled by contention. But remember: a 'workers' count that's proven optimal-throughput for one set of paramters may be wrong when these other core-calculation-changing parameters are varied.

There is an alternate mode to specify your corpus that more fully escapes Python GIL limitations: [a `corpus_file` parameter](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec) that, instead of streaming documents from a Python iterable collection, lets as many worker threads as you choose to read directly, independently, without contention from a corpus-on disk. This can potentially saturate as many cores as you have, but has a few caveats:

- the whole corpus must be a single file on disk, with a document per line, already tokenized by spaces - which can become unweildy with exactly the giant corpora on which this mode would be most attractive
- you lose the ability to specify your own document `tags` (keys to the doc-vectors), or more than one `tag` per document – instead each document's tag is only its single line-number
- this newer less-tested mode still shows some evidence of bugginess around the 'seams' between the ranges of the file that different threads train on, when tiny sections of the training data may be ignored - see [project issue #2757](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/2757) – and places where the performance varies for unclear reasons – see [project issue #3089](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/3089).

So: worth considering if your performance needs acute & hardware is plentiful, but you'll want to do some extra checks on the results.

Another consideration as your corpus grows: though *training* has some challenges to parallelize/distribute, and grows in duration with corpus, *inference* of doc-vectors for arbitrary new documents is easier to distribute, including across machines – by just moving copies of the frozen trained model to new machines. So if you've got a *representative* X million documents, sufficient in their coverage of vocab & themes to train a good model, you can then use that good model to infer 1000*X as many doc-vectors on other documents that were never part of training. (They'd not be available for lookup/most-similar ops from a single `Doc2Vec` model object, but could be accessed through other systems/vector-DBs.)

Finally, a couple other notes on your setup:

- It almost always improves these models to *increase* the `min_count` over its default of 5, as your corpus grows, rather than decrease. Rare words don[t get good word-vectors or contribute meaningfully to the doc-vector quality, but can (in aggregate) take up lots of the model state & training time. Pretending they aren't there, when too few to be helpful, tends to make the remaining vectors score better on downstream tasks. So don't assume "lower value means more data used and more data used can only help" – evaluate alternatives, because some rare words are essentially 'noise'.
- Often training on large corpora uses just 10-20 epochs and does fine, so 30 may be overkill. Something to test.
- With large corpora more-aggressive (lower) `sample` values are often a big win, *both* speeding training *and* improving results, by essentially spending less time on (& giving less influence to) very-frequent words. Again, sometimes to test.
- Make sure your `total_examples` as passed to `train()` matches the true count, or else both internal `alpha` learning-rate decay and logged reporting progress estimates will be handled wrong.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!  I will try out your suggestions to help, but it sounds like other than the experimental approach (only have words of each doc per line in corpus file, which has its own problems), there may not be a way to significantly scale up the training performance.  I assume a gpu will not help either?  Is this just the nature of doc2Vec?

Comment: Yes, `corpus_file` mode is the only way to fully saturate your large number of cores – but each of the other tactics may also offer big improvements. *Not* using excessive `workers` (worsening contention overhead) may quadruple or more your effective throughput & core-utilization. Removing extra processing (if any) in the existing `training_corpus` could be major. Larger `min_count` or smaller `sample` each reduce the effective corpus size for proportionately faster training – while also possibly improving vector quality.

Comment: Using fewer epochs linearly reduces training time, at potentilally little cost to final quality. And to extent some docs might not be needed for *model* training – they don't add much to the vocabulary/'concept-space' – leaving them out of training, for doc-vector inference with arbitrary parallelization later, can also effectively shrink the corpus/runtime. (The heuristic for which docs are less informative isn't clear, but those with no novel words/word-contexts might work.) Altogether, you might wind up 10x faster... even without `corpus_file` mode.

Comment: I tried lowering the epochs to 20, and got better results more quickly.  I tried lowering the sample to 0.00001 but got too many results that were inaccurate.  I tried raising min_count to 5 and got less results but they were still good, and didn't appear to lose anything good.  I tried corpus_file, which did increase performance by about 3x, but even then, the cores never exceeded 800%.  Using the corpus_file will require a bit of code modifications that I'm going to hold off on.  I think I will stick with epochs=20, min_count=5, sample=0.0001.  Thanks again for your insights.

Comment: Something to watch out for: if fewer epochs isn't just offering "as-good-results, but quicker", but objectively better results on a meaningful evaluation, there's a risk your model is too large for the variety in your data, and the larger epochs is overfitting, with the early-stop of the smaller-epochs fighting that somewhat. I think that'd be unlikely for true-natural-language data, with real variety, and (relatively small) 50d vectors – but if your data isn't real language, or otherwise somehow very repetitive/unnatural/synthetic (small unique vocabulary?), overfitting might be a risk.

Comment: Though at one level, "whatever works" including early-stopping may make sense, the more-theoretically-grounded approach would be to further shrink the model (larger `min_count` or smaller dimensionality) whenever you see evidence that more-epochs truly hurts on your ultimate/generlized goal. (That `sample=1e-05` hurt also suggests you might not be using fully-varied natural language, as I've *usually* seen that help on such large natural-language corpora.)

Comment: To the extent raising `min_count` a little will have both shrunk the model & sped training, without losing any good results, I'd continue to try larger values until they stop providing net-benefits. If your data isn't natural language, testing alternate `ns_exponent` values per the paper mentioned in the docs may offer benefits. And if even `corpus_file` mode maxes `workers=24` utilization around 800% rather than near 2400%, something like disk IO might be the real bottleneck – so ensuring corpus on superfast/local/etc volume might still give a benefit, in either `corpus_file` or classic mode.

Comment: Alternatively, if sure that IO isn't a limit, something in the BLAS library where it's *also* trying to do its own parallelism might be causing unplanned contention - and trying to limit that level's multithreading *may* resolve some unhelpful contention, per (for example) adjusting the environment variables mentioned in answers at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy - note this must be done before numpy/BLAS loaded to have desired effect.

Comment: I am using natural language, but there are some real problems with the quality due to OCR issues in a significant portion of the documents.
I'm using an Annoy Index with 100 trees to perform inference against the trained model and I only accept scores above 0.7.
I'm building on AWS machines with EBS volumes and I didn't see any disk load when building the model, so I don't think disk IO is an issue (unless AWS is masking it).
When I lowered sample to 0.00001, the number of hits (and processing time) increased 5x, but I only got a 12% increase in good hits.

Comment: If by "scores above 0.7" means cosine-similarities, I would caution against using any fixed threshold for quality-of-matches – as those can vary quite a lot when varying model parameters changes "spacing" of docs/words, while relative-rankings still suggest the right (or better) things at lower absolute similarities. (There's a risk that any rule-of-thumb that seems to check out at one set of training params, like "evetyhing closer than 0.7 is a candidate" is no longer a similar guide in a slightly-different model; re-calibrating on an external or user-driven quality-score is important.)

Comment: EG, if you get 5x more "hits over threshold=0.7" with new para (like `sample=1e-05`), it may instead make sense go threshold=0.8, so you get exactly the same x count of candidates - but now 90% of those x candidates check out as 'good', whereas in old model 50% of top-x were 'good'. ie: all the items may have been pushed "closer" in overall space, but (re-calibrated) their relative positions may be more informative. (Check out a tranformation proposed in a paper titled 'all but the top' for something that *might* improve salience/contrast as postprocessing, esp with `negative=15`.)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that *if* something like `sample=1e-05` speeds processing 5x, that could open practical space for other experiments that would otherwise grow training time too much – like far more `epochs` (to be sure model converges) or yet-higher `negative`, or PV-DM (`dm=1`) mode or `dbow_words=1` (adding some level of word-to-word training).

Comment: And you've probably already thought of this, but if OCR issues seriously impair the vocab (by splitting meaningful words into sub-`min_count` versions that are lost, or simply rarer variants with weaker/more-arbitrary representations that inject noise in the doc2vec training/inference), a preprocessing fixup step that statistically merges likely typos/scannos into their more-common canonical versions might be worth the effort. (Finding what 'realer' words that rarer tokens should be transformed into could be edit-distance based and/or even word2vec/FastText-influenced.)