python multiprocessing gets slower with additional cpus
I'm trying to parallelize code that should be embarrassingly parallel and it just seems to get slower the more processes I use.  Here is a minimally (dys)functional example:
import os
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def pool_func(
    number: int,
    max_number: int
) -> dict:
    
    pid = str(multiprocessing.current_process().pid)
    
    print('[{:2d}/{:2d} {:s}] Starting ...'.format(number, max_number, pid))
    t0 = time.time()
    # # the following takes ~10 seconds on a separate node
    # for i in range(2):
    #     print('[{:d}] Passed loop {:d}/2...'.format(number, i+1))
    #     time.sleep(5)
    
    # the following takes ~3.3 seconds on a separate node
    n = 1000
    for _ in range(50):
        u = np.random.randn(n, n)
        v = np.linalg.inv(u)
    
    t1 = time.time()
    print('[{:2d}/{:2d} {:s}] Finished in {:.1f} seconds.'.format(number, max_number, pid, t1 - t0))
    return {}
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runs = []
    count = 0
    while count < 50:
        runs.append(
            (count, 50)
        )
        count += 1
    
    print(f"Number of runs to perform: {len(runs):d}")
    
    num_cpus = 4
    print(f"Running job with {num_cpus:d} CPUs in parallel ...")
    
    # with Pool(processes=num_cpus) as pool:
    with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool(processes=num_cpus) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(pool_func, runs)
    
    print('Main process done.')

There are three features I want to point out.  First, num_cpus can be changed to increase the number of workers in the pool. Second, I can change from the default 'fork' pool to the 'spawn' method, this doesn't seem to change anything.  Finally, inside pool_func, the process that is running can be either a CPU intensive matrix inversion or a CPU-absent wait function.
When I use the wait function, the processes run in approximately the correct time, about 10 seconds per process.  When I use the matrix inversion, the process time increases with the number of processes in the following, approximate, way:
1 CPU :  3 seconds  
2 CPUs:  4 seconds  
4 CPUs: 30 seconds  
8 CPUs: 95 seconds  

Here is a partial output of the script above, run as-is:
Number of runs to perform: 50
Running job with 4 CPUs in parallel ...
[ 0/50 581194] Starting ...
[ 4/50 581193] Starting ...
[ 8/50 581192] Starting ...
[12/50 581191] Starting ...
[ 0/50 581194] Finished in 24.7 seconds.
[ 1/50 581194] Starting ...
[ 4/50 581193] Finished in 29.3 seconds.
[ 5/50 581193] Starting ...
[12/50 581191] Finished in 30.3 seconds.
[13/50 581191] Starting ...
[ 8/50 581192] Finished in 32.2 seconds.
[ 9/50 581192] Starting ...
[ 1/50 581194] Finished in 26.9 seconds.
[ 2/50 581194] Starting ...
[ 5/50 581193] Finished in 30.3 seconds.
[ 6/50 581193] Starting ...
[13/50 581191] Finished in 30.8 seconds.
[14/50 581191] Starting ...
[ 9/50 581192] Finished in 32.8 seconds.
[10/50 581192] Starting ...
...

The process ids look unique to me.
Clearly, there is some problem with scaling as adding more CPUs is causing the processes to run slower.  There isn't any I/O at all in the processes that are being timed.  These are pedestrian processes that I expected would work right out of the box.  I have no idea why this is not working as I think it should.  Why does this script have individual processes that take longer when I use more CPUs?
When I run this on my macos laptop, it works as expected.  But has similar scaling issues on a different remote linux computer I have access to.  This might be a platform specific problem, but I'll leave it up in case someone has seen it before and knows how to fix it.

numpy.random.randn: "New code should use the standard_normal method of a Generator instance instead". May be it's not about cpus but rather about generating random data. Also; https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html

Making that change doesn't fix the problem.  Also, this is just a stand-in for a different script that doesn't use the same rng.  I would be surprised if this is the issue.  Thank you, nonetheless.

What's the load average of the 1 CPU version, 2 CPU version, 8 CPU version, etc? I ask because NumPy parallelizes some operations internally. You can use htop to investigate this. If there one thread per process, and then you get load average equal to the number of processes after the program has run for a minute or so. If you have many threads per process, then you can get load averages which exceed the number of CPUs. It's possible for multiple NumPy threadpools to fight over the same set of CPUs.

When I look at htop while the script is running with 4 CPUs, all 256 of the CPUs are at or near 100%.

It is strange that this works without issue on my macbook, but doesn't work on either of the linux systems I work with.

Seems numpy uses different libraries depending on how it was installed. BLAS and LAPACK. Also related.

Putting in a numpy-less function that takes a while into pool_func fixes this problem.  It appears that numpy is hogging all the CPUs.  This script is a cut down version of a script that mostly used pytorch instead of numpy.  Maybe I need to figure out how to limit the number of threads that numpy/pytorch can use.

@FinncentPrice You can use the threadpoolctl package to control how many threads NumPy uses. I have a blog post here about how to use this: https://njodell.com/?p=74

For PyTorch specifically, they have this docs page about threads: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cpu_threading_torchscript_inference.html See also https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_num_threads.html

@NickODell Your suggestions put me on the right path.  The script no longer slows down when I put this answer at the top: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224849/6024187. Similarly, torch.set_num_threads() appears to fix the issue for pytorch.  If you want to condense this into an answer, I will select it.

There is something very odd about your runtime platform. Running your code exactly as shown in the question, the reported durations average ~3.3s

One thing that can cause this kind of problem is nested parallelism, when each process in your process pool starts multiple threads to speed up operations within that process.
You can investigate whether this is happening is by looking at one minute load average. A program like htop can show you this. Run your program with varying process counts. If there one thread per process, and then you get load average close to the number of processes after the program has run for a minute or so. If you have many threads per process, then you can get load averages which are much higher than the number of processes.
If this happens, you can frequently get better results by limiting or eliminating NumPy parallelism, so that the number of threads times the number of processes is equal to your number of CPU cores.
There are two ways you can do this.

threadpoolctl can adjust thread count in NumPy. You can do this once at process startup, or limit parallelism only in sections that you know won't benefit from parallelism.
Example:
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_limits
import numpy as np

with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api='blas'):
    # In this block, calls to blas implementation (like openblas or MKL)
    # will be limited to use only one thread. They can thus be used jointly
    # with thread-parallelism.
    a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
    a_squared = a @ a

Be aware that these limits are not shared between processes, so you'll need to call threadpool_limits() in the subprocess, not the parent process.

Most BLAS libraries will read configuration for the number of threads from an environment variable, and limit their thread pool accordingly. You can see a common list of environment variables here.
I am not a big fan of this approach, for two reasons. The first reason is that this depends on library load order. The environment variable needs to be set before NumPy is imported. The second reason is that it doesn't allow you to dynamically set threadpool size, which makes it harder to make targeted, small fixes.



You need to call the Multiprocessing.pool inside of the function and have it map directly to the numpy matrix inversion.
But, if the task is not big enough I cant guarantee that it will speed it up.
The independent cost of setting up the process might outdo the singular execution of each.
"Embarassingly Parrellel" is a term used for GPU multiprocessing. Currently python doesnt support native gpu acceleration.

The numpy matrix inversion is a dummy process that takes a while.  I don't care about matrix inversion, per se.

You are calling a high level class to do complex multiprocessing on an interpreted language, rarely will it do exactly what you want it to do. You need to skip using the multiprocessing.Pool and write a custom multiprocessing.Process & multiprocessing.Queue script to allow for more control. This will ensure Interprocess communication doesnt slow it down and true multiprocessing is upheld.

@TheCableGUI it doesn't have anything to do with that. The problem is the BLAS/LAPACK C libraries inside numpy starting their own threads and causing massive resource contention - which is not solvable by fiddling with Process and Queue, or really anything python related. Pool will work perfectly as expected if BLAS is limited to 1 (or other reasonable number) of threads.

can you show me this?

and it has everything to do with "embarrassing parallel". If you arent doing the lowest form of computation on a thread or process then you arent following the simd or simt models.

@TheCableGUI there's two ways to see it - 1) if you run OP's code with num_cpus=1, and look at your system usage, you'll see it's maxing every core, or at least, definitely not just using 1 CPU (depending on what libraries your system has that numpy has decided to use). BLAS/LINPACK/OMP/MKL/etc library is where all the good hyperoptimized SIMD stuff happens. 2) if you use threadpoolctl like Nick ODell's answer to the question shows, and you limit the BLAS library to only use 1 thread, the expected/original performance is restored
