# Python: significant difference in performance between local installation and virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I observed a significant difference in performance between my local Python (2.7) and a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) (on the same machine).

I tested the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import time

A = np.random.rand(500, 3000)
B = np.random.rand(5000, 3000)

tic = time.time()
p = np.dot(A, B.T)
toc = time.time()
print toc - tic
```

It was ~20 times faster in the local environment.

What could be the reasons? (Maybe there is a package that accelerates vectorized operations installed in the my local Python but not on the virtual environment?)

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a difference in the numpy versions?

Comment: Likewise, is the same version of python running in the virtual environment?

Comment: Thanks, @MartinKonecny and Gil. The versions are indeed different (2.7.6 vs 2.7.11). I'll upgrade and check again.

Comment: More important than the numpy version is the BLAS implementation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511430/performance-of-numpy-with-different-blas-implementations. Do you know which BLAS version (if any) is being used by each numpy?

Comment: Yes, @BiRico, this was indeed the reason. I do not have BLAS or LAPACK in my virtual environment. My local Python is from Anaconda and it has everything in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @BiRico, I checked the version of Linear Algebra libraries such as BLAS and LAPACK using the command:

```
python -c 'import numpy; numpy.show_config()'
```

and surprised, I do not have any of these installed.