# Why is numpy and scipy exp() faster than log()?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

In general, log and exp functions should be roughly the same speed. I would expect the numpy and scipy implementations to be relative straightforward wrappers. `numpy.log()` and `scipy.log()` have similar speed as expected. However, I found that `numpy.log()` is ~60% slower than these `exp()` functions and `scipy.log()` is 100% slower. Does anyone one know the reason for this?

Comment: In my simple tests, `np.log` is 60% faster.  Yes, list comprehensions using `math.log` and `math.exp` give the same times.  But the numpy code isn't (necessarily) a simple compiled loop using the `math` equivalents.

Comment: Why do you think that log and exp should be "roughly the same speed"?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think that both should be "roughly the same speed". It's true that both *can* be calculated using a Taylor series (which, even by itself means little without analyzing the error term), but then the numerical tricks kick in.

E.g., [an algebraic identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation) can be used to transform  the original exp. Taylor series into a more efficient 2-jump power series. However, for the power series, see [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra619/spra619.pdf) a discussion of by-case optimizations, some of which involve a lookup table.

---

Which arguments did you give the functions - the same? the worst one for each?

What was the accuracy of the results? And how do you measure the accuracy for each: absolutely, relatively?

---

**Edit** It should be noted that these libraries can also have [different backends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671040/link-atlas-mkl-to-an-installed-numpy).