# how can i make numpy use BLAS and LAPACK after being installed?

Tags: numpy

Numpy in my computer is quite slow and I am suspecting that it is not using BLAS or LAPACK. When I run numpy.**config**.show(), I get the following output:

```
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = c
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = f77
atlas_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = f77
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = c
mkl_info:
  NOT
```

The problem is that those library directories do not exist on my computer. I have no idea how those directories have sneaked in to the numpy config. Is there anyway to change a setting so that numpy can use the optimized BLAS and LAPACK after being installed? Or, should I re-install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21671040/1461210

Answer (score 0):

The key will be a version of a `site.cfg` file, tuned to your system. You can find numpy's example, `site.cfg.example`, [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/site.cfg.example). When I did this on Linux, I cloned numpy from source, edited that file as described in the comments, and ran `python setup.py install` in the numpy directory, and it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `blas`. These are the libraries you are using.

```
 blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = c
```

You are using `lapack`.

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\local\\lib\\atlas\\sse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', -1)]
    language = f77
```

You are **not** using blas_mkl and lapack_mkl. These are proprietary implementations of those libraries.

I hope that you aren't thinking `numpy` will compare in speed to direct implementations of `blas` and `lapack`. It will be an order of magnitude slower.