# Linking numpy to linear algebra and optimization libraries

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, atlas

I have been trying to link my numpy installation to various Linear Algebra and Optimization libraries that exists in the system. It currently does not have any `_doatlas.so` file in `/numpy/core` because of which `numpy.disutils` does not exist.

How can I link my existing atlas, blas and lapack `.so` files to existing numpy installation?

However I have my scipy correctly linked to above files.

```
    In [5]: scipy.__config__.show()
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas', '/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
atlas_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas', '/usr/lib/atlas-base']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include/atlas']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Compiling Numpy with OpenBLAS integration : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration/14391693#14391693

Comment: Link installed Numpy to the libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671040/link-atlas-mkl-to-an-installed-numpy