# Lasagne/Theano doesn't consume multi cores while check_blas.py does

Tags: numpy, theano, keras, multicore, lasagne

I'm running a Logistic Regression classifier on Lasagne/Theano with multiple **cpu** cores.

This is my *~/.theanorc* file:

```
[global]
OMP_NUM_THREADS=20
```

theano/misc/**check_blas.py** consumes all 20 cores but my script doesn't.
when I run:

```
python -c 'import theano; print(theano.config)'
```

I see that the value of openmp is False:

> openmp () 
>       Doc:  Allow (or not) parallel computation on the CPU with OpenMP. This is the default value used when creating an Op that supports
>   OpenMP parallelization. It is preferable to define it via the Theano
>   configuration file ~/.theanorc or with the environment variable
>   THEANO_FLAGS. Parallelization is only done for some operations that
>   implement it, and even for operations that implement parallelism, each
>   operation is free to respect this flag or not. You can control the
>   number of threads used with the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.
>   If it is set to 1, we disable openmp in Theano by default.
>       **Value:  False**

Does anybody know How I should enable the multi-core feature for my script?

blas, atlas, openmp, etc. are installed on my system and as I said work perfectly with check_blas.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason. Besides *OMP_NUM_THREADS=20*, **openmp=True** should also be set in the ~/.theanorc file and now it consumes all the 20 cores.
My **~/.theanorc** file now looks like:

```
[global]
OMP_NUM_THREADS=20
openmp=True
```

Comment: Note that if you're using sudo you should put the .theanorc file in /root.

Comment: If the threads are created but they don't utilise the CPU, one way is to install openblas from source and configure and build numpy from source to point to that as well described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration

Comment: Also if you want to connect your already installed numpy to openblas read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671040/link-atlas-mkl-to-an-installed-numpy

Comment: In some cases adding this to .theanorc also helps: [blas] ldflags=-L/usr/lib/ -lblas -lgfortran