# Is there a way to link PyPI's numpy to MKL on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, intel-mkl

I have a `numpy` version installed on Mac via `pip install numpy`, which [by default is shipped](https://numpy.org/install/#numpy-packages--accelerated-linear-algebra-libraries) (and is linked against) the OpenBLAS implementation of BLAS and LAPACK.

Is it possible to make `numpy` use MKL (which I manually installed) without using `conda` or compiling `numpy` from source? I know that there's a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21673585/1756478) to make it work on Linux, but is this possible on Mac as well? if yes, is it a good idea (e.g. copying and renaming `libmkl_core.dylib` to `libopenblas.0.dylib`?)