# Install Scipy with MKL through PIP

Tags: python, linux, scipy, pip, intel-mkl

I am using PIP to install Scipy with MKL to accelerate the performance. My OS is Ubuntu 64 bit. Using the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769936/supplying-numpy-site-cfg-arguments-to-pip), I create a file .numpy-site.cfg

```
[mkl]
library_dirs=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/
include_dirs=/opt/intel/mkl/include/
mkl_libs=mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,mkl_rt
lapack_libs=
```

This file helps me to install Numpy with MKL successfully. However, using the same above file, installing Scipy prompts the error

```
ImportError: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64
```

but the problem is still the same.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? I don't want to install Scipy manually so anyone give me some hints to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: I have tried this option before. However, the error is still in. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: You have to check whether these libraries actually exist at the specified locations with `library_dirs` and `include_dirs`. There could be many reasons why this is not the case. The most obvious ones being that you installed an older/newer Intel Studio version or you installed the compiler and the libraries to a non-default location.

Answer (score 18):

Intel has been publishing wheels of packages like Numpy, Scipy and Scikit-learn to PyPI. These wheels have been built while linking against Intel MKL, and include various optimizations.

If you want Scipy built with Intel MKL:

```
#Remove existing Numpy and/or Scipy:
pip uninstall numpy scipy -y
#Install scipy built with Intel MKL:
pip install intel-scipy
```

[More information available here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-distribution-for-python-and-intel-performance-libraries-with-pip-and)

Comment: This does not work as of March 2019 for Python 3.7. Pip does not find an "intel-scipy" on the repository.

Comment: I had python 3.6.9 and it worked. You might also need to get the llibpython. `apt install libpython3.6`. I verified my installation inside python with `numpy.show_config()`

Answer (score 5):

2 years have passed since this question was asked.

There are now numpy/scipy wheels for linux that use a openblas compiled for avx2, so you can get much better performance without building packages. You may need to upgrade pip to get it to install the wheel:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy scipy
```

If you want MKL, then you can install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Intel Distribution for Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-distribution-for-python). They use conda instead of pip to manage packages, but they are free and distribute packages that contain all the dependences, including MKL.

Comment: There isn't a wheel for Ubuntu which the OP is using. The best choice would be Anaconda.

Answer (score 5):

I have Win10 64Bit with Python 3.6.2 i have installed scipy through http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

I followed following steps :

- Step 1: Uninstall if you have any previous version of numpy, 
         pip uninstall numpy
- Step 2 : Download numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl with
  MKL(Math Kernel Library) from below link,
         http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
- Step 3: copy downloaded file into another location and launch command
  prompt from that location.
- Step 4: run this command,
         pip install -U numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
- Step 5: Now Download scipy library from,
         http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
- Step 6: Copy downloaded file into same location in which numpy is
  copied.
- Step 7: In CMD prompt run this cmd,
         pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Done!

Comment: that is for windows. dude.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, great answer and great representation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are having trouble installing or running with specific version then first uninstall and then install

Step 1:

```
pip uninstall -v numpy
```

Step 2: download the wheel file and install

```
pip install -U numpy-1.13.0+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

In this example wheel file name is "numpy-1.13.0+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
"

Comment: Please let me know what did you do? Did you follow the steps i suggested?

Comment: Sorry. It is such a long time. I have not used this server anymore so cannot apply your solution.

Comment: OP explicitly said Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing this problem the past few weeks on:
Windows 10 64 bit Python 3.5.2

My workaround:

First: `pip install wheel`

Next: Download Numpy and Scipy form Gholke's repo
[Numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and [SciPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

Then:

`pip install numpy_package.whl`

`pip install scipy_package.whl`

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual question itself was not answered, let me give it a shot...

I think the problem here basically is that the BLAS/LAPACK libraries being used are spread out across multiple location, and numpy doesn't handle this well.

We have fixed this in EasyBuild, where we have been building numpy/scipy on top of Intel MKL for a while now, with this patch: https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild-easyconfigs/blob/master/easybuild/easyconfigs/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.1-mkl.patch

Answer (score 0):

For me, MKL came with Scipy library by `conda install scipy`

@rscohn2 solution gave me a hint for using packages.

For the reference, my environment is included Ubuntu, Anaconda, Python 3.6, Scipy 1.1 and MKL 2018.0.