# pip install "Invalid requirement: 'numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64'"

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I am on a windows 10 machine and I can't seem to get it to install numpy+mkl. I have no clue what is going on or why it is doing this. It says the following errors occurred in the most recent Traceback:

```css
File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 92, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)"
File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1617, in parseString
    raise exc"
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1607, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3164, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 12), (line:1, col:13)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "..\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+mkl-cp3
```

I've been sitting for hours trying to figure out what this means. But it is alien to me. I tried to update it, but it says it is already up to date. I've tried using the 32bit wheel it gives me the same thing. What should I do?

Comment: You could use the [Intel Distribution for Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python). Alternatively, Intel has a nice [guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl) for installing numpy/scipy with mkl.

Comment: did you install mkl? I remember in linux have to edit a file in the numpy source code to specify the location of mkl. try intel distribution for python if you just want numpy+mkl. Or anaconda if you have a bit more time and want more packages. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to install mkl on its own. I think I did but, I do not know. I downloaded the numpy+mkl whl file, but every time  I try to pip install it it says it isn't a proper wheel file. I am at a complete loss on what to do. I just want to learn how to make things machine learn, and this is a big hurdle for me.
When I use the whole path, it ask me if the path exist. I mean I copy it from the file location so idk why it asks that.

Answer (score 1):

I installed it.

I finally found a link [Answer is 3rd post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991420/install-scipy-with-mkl-through-pip)

I don't know why I just found this, but it took long enough. I needed to uninstall it and then give it a .whl extension. I didn't notice that it didn't have the .whl extension when I was trying to install it. Also, I had to make sure that I used the whole file location.