# Cannot find BLAS on a machine with MKL when installing scipy

Tags: scipy, pip, blas, intel-mkl

I installed Intel MKL and other libraries for a customized numpy. Here is my `~/.numpy-site.cfg`:

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = /usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
include_dirs = /usr/include:/usr/local/include

[mkl]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/
include_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/include/
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs =

[amd]
amd_libs = amd

[umfpack]
umfpack_libs = umfpack

[djbfft]
include_dirs = /usr/local/djbfft/include
library_dirs = /usr/local/djbfft/lib
```

This configuration file seems OK during the installation of numpy. But when I was installing scipy via `pip3 install scipy`, it reported that

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.
```

In my mind MKL is an implementation of Blas so just mentioning MKL should be fine. I've tried

1. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH‌​`
2. `export BLAS=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64`
3. Copy the content in the `[mkl]` section and paste into the `[blas]` section in the file `~/.numpy-site.cfg`

But none of these works. So what is going wrong? Does scipy respect `~/.numpy-site.cfg`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the extension on your libs in `..../intel64`? I had a similar problem where because the extensions where `.so.3.0` the the setup script was not finding the libraries. My solution was to create symlinks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23325759/1430829 . Maybe this will work for you too?

Comment: The extension is `*.so` and `*.a` (like `libmkl_blas95_ilp64.a` and `libmkl_intel_ilp64.so`).