# sudo pip3 install numpy does not respect ~/.numpy-site.cfg

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, sudo

I'm trying to install numpy and scipy on python3 using pip3. I want to use MKL, so I've specified as much in `~/.numpy-site.cfg` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769936/supplying-numpy-site-cfg-arguments-to-pip?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671040/link-atlas-mkl-to-an-installed-numpy?lq=1)):

```
[mkl]
library_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
include_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/include
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs =
extra_compile_args = -march=native
```

I then install numpy (successfully) via

```
$ sudo pip3 install numpy
```

However, MKL does not show up in the config!

```
>>> np.show_config()
...
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
...
```

Installing scipy subsequently fails (as expected) with

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

However, when I install numpy and scipy in a virtualenv on the same machine without changing anything else, MKL *is* found, and scipy works fine.

My first guess was that sudo was not picking up `$HOME`, but `sudo echo $HOME` returns my home directory correctly.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the python executable you are using is the same one used in the `pip3` command (for example, `head -n1 \`which pip3\`` should tell you). Or make sure you use the correct pip to install things: `sudo python3 -m pip install numpy` or whatever python executable you use.

Comment: any reason you're not using Anaconda? it's not really recommended to install numpy with pip

Comment: You don't happen to have a `site.cfg` lying around somewhere with empty mkl info in it?

Comment: @Evert Nope, I'm using the right pip3 - I checked with `which`. I don't have a site.cfg lying around anywhere either...

Comment: @maxymoo Not recommended? This is the first I'm hearing of this... But to answer your question, I'm not using Anaconda because I want to custom-link scipy to MKL, not use whatever default ATLAS and BLAS that come with Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my guess was indeed correct. `sudo` *isn't* using the right `$HOME`. `sudo echo $HOME` worked because bash expanded `$HOME` before calling sudo to run the command.

The following test did the trick though:

```
# In test.sh
echo "$HOME"
```

And now I get

```
$ sudo bash test.sh
/root
```

which confirms that `$HOME` is incorrect. It turns out that a bunch of settings had been set in /etc/sudoers (always_set_home and env_reset), which meant that `sudo -E bash test.sh` had no effect either.

I finally just installed it with

```
$ sudo HOME=/path/to/my/home pip3 install numpy
```

which worked.

Comment: I later discovered that this worked on a RHEL7 machine but not on an Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. I still have no clue how to get it to work for Ubuntu. I just ended up installing from source...